# PHP session overlap

Tags: php, browser, session-cookies

First I log in with one user and then I open a second tab and log in with other user.
Now the problem is that when I go to the tab where I logged in first and refresh it, the username from the second tab overlaps the first one.

I have seen that the two different users have different cookies, but is the second one overlapping the first one, because I try to log in with more than one user on a single machine..My theory is that I am only getting the last session and it sets it everyhwere.So I am wondering how can I make them independent.
This is my PHP code for the session of each user:
`

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]))
{
    $mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/databaseCon.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE user_id = {$_SESSION["user_id"]}";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $getSessions = $mysqli->query("SELECT sessionName FROM sessions");

}
```

`This is my login script. Once logged in, they will be sent to different pages determined by the roles(student or a teacher):`

```
<?php

$is_invalid = false;
#if we opened the page its set to GET, when we submit POST
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{
    $mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/databaseCon.php";

    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE email = '%s'", 
        $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mail"]));

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($user)
    {
        if(password_verify($_POST["passw"], $user["password_hash"]))
        {

            session_start();

            session_regenerate_id();

            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user["user_id"];
            $_SESSION["firstName"] = $user["firstName"];
            $_SESSION["privilege"] = $user["privilege"];

            header("Location: /Controllers/sessionInit.php");
            exit;

        }
    }
    $is_invalid = true;
}



?>
```

`

Comment: Regular tabs (and windows) within the same browser on the same machine share the same state for a website. Cookies, localStorage, etc. If you want to be able to log in as two different users on the same machine, either use different browsers or use private browsing mode (incognito mode) for the other user.

Comment: Plus: You should not be able to log in if you are already logged in. Your code should reflect that.

Comment: Plus: You should not be able to log in if you are already logged in. Your code should reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

When your php program feeds its session cookie to the browser, the browser then uses it, immediately, for all its tabs. So starting a session for Bob disconnects your browser from the session for Alice.

It's common during debugging to want to have two user sessions going at once. When I do that, I do one of three things

1. Use different browsers for different sessions (Chrome, Firefox, Edge etc).
2. Use a browser's anonymous mode for the second session.
3. Set up multiple user profiles in the browser, and use the different profiles for different sessions. This can be clunky, however.